# how to remove bracket and name when modelchoicefield is used in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

Here is my code:

```
staff_id=forms.ModelChoiceField(label="Staff",widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class":"form- 
control"}),queryset=Staff.objects.all().values('name'))
```

Here is my output:

I am getting this name and brackets in this pop down menu, how can i remove these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use value_list instead as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

> This is similar to values() except that instead of returning
> dictionaries, it returns tuples when iterated over

---

> If you only pass in a single field, you can also pass in the flat
> parameter. If True, this will mean the returned results are single
> values

```
values_list('name', flat=True)
```

Comment: I am getting an issue, as i used modelfieldchoice, it is working fine but in forms where it displays name,in database it is also delivering name in field of foreign key id. Previously, i was saving the id in database but showing the name in pop down menu but reloading server error was coming but now i replaced it with modelchoicefield it shows me name and in database, it is also saving name but i want key to save. how can i do that?